# can using trigger i call external java class in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, triggers

Can I trigger an external program to run when a new record is added to
the mysql table?

The external program is in java and instead of scanning the table
continuously for new insertions, it will be better if an external
program could be triggered.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: records are being inserted from ?

Comment: What is the design like? Can you change the application that adds a new record to the mysql table? then why not just change that application?

Comment: i am using elastic search for search,here all searching are done on indexes not in database.when new record's are add into database my trigger call java class that update index for new records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling external programs will cause inconsistency in your transactions and corrupt your data if your program were to fail, reconsider your approach to do this from the application side.